# How do I configure a BungeeCord-server, in order to access my playerlist?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bungeecord

I'm trying to access the playerlist of a BungeeCord-server to fetch the playerlist (who's online, NOT how many users are online) to access it later on by a .php file on the same Server.
I build this once before without BungeeCord - I just needed to enable the queryport on the `server.properties`. IIRC i did not even need to configure a port, i guess it was just using the standard port 25565 or something.

But there's the problem:
I tried to configure the properties with Enable-Query=true and set the port to any port at first and to none afterwords.

Both cases didn't work.
I got the server restarted after both tries but it didn't get better.

I checked the query with both a [script by xPaw](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query) and [minecraft-api.com](http://minecraft-api.com/documentation#query)

As this is not just my Server and there are always some users online, I can't use a try and error answer :/

If it's possible I don't want to install a new plugin for this if Minecraft supports this feature on its own.

Comment: Do you know how to get to your bungeecord config?

Comment: I think so.
Like it was in Vanilla there is a config file, but changing this was not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Bungeecord the `config.yml` file in your server root directory contains the `query_enabled: true` and `query_port: 25565` settings.  Setting these to true and an available port will bring you the same results you had before you switched to Bungee.  Also do not forget to restart your bungee server after you change the config file.

Comment: This answer is correct, though it wasn't the solution for me.
My problem was, the skripts of xPaw and senither do both work with sockets, which weren't activated by our system admin.
But thanks anyway!